# How do I select the interaction coefficients to keep in Stata?

Tags: stata

Similar to the question posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756214/stata-choose-which-interaction-to-omit-using-factor-variables-and-fixed-effects), but I think I am not employing it correctly.

I used `help fvvarlist` to guide me on interactions.
I am employing a triple interaction with 3 binary variables:

As a toy model, let us assume:

```
x = gender (1 = male, 0 = female)  
y = health (1 = good, 0 = poor)   
z = employment (1 = employed, 0 = not employed)
```

using the following regression:

```
reg x##y##z if state == "NY" & year >1985
```

I am interested in the results for `1.x#1.y#1.z`, but this coefficient is omitted.
**`1.x#1.y#1.z omitted because of collinearity`**
Is there a way I can keep this interaction?

Comment: The implication is that you're not missing anything, as the triple interaction wouldn't give you extra information.  This is not a programming question as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to verify that you actually have this combination in your data with `egen, group`.

You should also use i. prefixes to keep Stata from treating your variables as continuous, which has the added benefit of a more informative error message: interaction identifies no observations in the sample rather than a mysterious collinearity one.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 automobile data)

. sum mpg weight

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |         74     21.2973    5.785503         12         41
      weight |         74    3019.459    777.1936       1760       4840

. gen efficient = mpg > 21

. lab define efficient 0 "Inefficient" 1 "Efficient"

. lab val efficient efficient

. gen heavy = weight > 3e3 

. lab define heavy 0 "Light" 1 "Heavy"

. lab val heavy heavy

. egen group = group(foreign efficient heavy), label(group)

. tab group, sort

   group(foreign efficient |
                    heavy) |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
---------------------------+-----------------------------------
Domestic Inefficient Heavy |         34       45.95       45.95
   Foreign Efficient Light |         15       20.27       66.22
  Domestic Efficient Light |         13       17.57       83.78
 Foreign Inefficient Light |          5        6.76       90.54
  Domestic Efficient Heavy |          3        4.05       94.59
Domestic Inefficient Light |          2        2.70       97.30
 Foreign Inefficient Heavy |          2        2.70      100.00
---------------------------+-----------------------------------
                     Total |         74      100.00

. reg price c.foreign##c.efficient##c.heavy, robust
note: c.foreign#c.efficient#c.heavy omitted because of collinearity.

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =         74
                                                F(6, 67)          =      74.67
                                                Prob > F          =     0.0000
                                                R-squared         =     0.2830
                                                Root MSE          =     2606.9

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                              |               Robust
                        price | Coefficient  std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
                      foreign |     3007.6   960.0626     3.13   0.003     1091.307    4923.893
                    efficient |   513.2308   394.6504     1.30   0.198    -274.4948    1300.956
                              |
        c.foreign#c.efficient |  -1810.164   1071.875    -1.69   0.096    -3949.636    329.3076
                              |
                        heavy |   3283.176   696.5873     4.71   0.000     1892.782    4673.571
                              |
            c.foreign#c.heavy |   2462.724   1196.996     2.06   0.044     73.50896    4851.938
                              |
          c.efficient#c.heavy |  -2783.741   744.4813    -3.74   0.000    -4269.732    -1297.75
                              |
c.foreign#c.efficient#c.heavy |          0  (omitted)
                              |
                        _cons |       3739   332.9212    11.23   0.000     3074.486    4403.514
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. reg price i.foreign##i.efficient##i.heavy, robust
note: 1.foreign#1.efficient#1.heavy identifies no observations in the sample.

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =         74
                                                F(6, 67)          =      74.67
                                                Prob > F          =     0.0000
                                                R-squared         =     0.2830
                                                Root MSE          =     2606.9

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                         |               Robust
                   price | Coefficient  std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
                 foreign |
                Foreign  |     3007.6   960.0626     3.13   0.003     1091.307    4923.893
                         |
               efficient |
              Efficient  |   513.2308   394.6504     1.30   0.198    -274.4948    1300.956
                         |
       foreign#efficient |
      Foreign#Efficient  |  -1810.164   1071.875    -1.69   0.096    -3949.636    329.3076
                         |
                   heavy |
                  Heavy  |   3283.176   696.5873     4.71   0.000     1892.782    4673.571
                         |
           foreign#heavy |
          Foreign#Heavy  |   2462.724   1196.996     2.06   0.044     73.50896    4851.938
                         |
         efficient#heavy |
        Efficient#Heavy  |  -2783.741   744.4813    -3.74   0.000    -4269.732    -1297.75
                         |
 foreign#efficient#heavy |
Foreign#Efficient#Heavy  |          0  (empty)
                         |
                   _cons |       3739   332.9212    11.23   0.000     3074.486    4403.514
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There are no foreign, efficient, and heavy cars in the data, and when you let Stata know that you have categorical variables on the RHS, you get an understandable error message about why the triple interaction is missing.